# How to add additional primary shards to Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have a cluster containing 7 nodes, I've recently noticed that we are only using 5 primary shards, meaning that per index - we are only utilizing 5 nodes out of 7.
I would like to add two additional primary shards for newly created indices.

I've added the following to elasticsearch.yml and restarted the cluster:

index.number_of_shards: 7
index.number_of_replicas: 0

However, it's been a few days and a few new indices since - and I still see its sharding to 5 pieces.. can anyone explain why? am I missing some additional configuration here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reindex affected index. As I imagine there is only 1 index in the cluster. Number of shards can not change automatically in an existing index.

[This relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941871/re-indexing-an-index-in-elasticsearch-to-change-the-number-of-shards) might help and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851044/is-there-a-smarter-way-to-reindex-elasticsearch) if you do not want any downtime, it works with aliases and basically 2 indexes- 1 before resharding and 1 afterwards and then you switch aliases to point in wherever index you want

Comment: Guys - Thanks for the comments but I think you misunderstand, I have new indices created every day at midnight, i just want new indices to be created with more shards. old indices will eventually phase out. is that possible?

Comment: @user3352229 Can you post `GET /yourdailyindices/_settings` for indices before you change shard number and after?

Comment: here is the settings of an index that was created after i changed the setting and restarted the cluster:
{
"2015-05-12" : {
"settings" : {
"index" : {
"creation_date" : "1431388790550",
"uuid" : "H5bzXRekT0WDni2BEDJsfA",
"number_of_replicas" : "0",
"number_of_shards" : "5",
"version" : {
"created" : "1040499"
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: its still creating indices with default value of 5 primary shards, looks like its ignoring the setting in elasticsearch.yml for index.number_of_shards: 7

Comment: @user3352229 Did you restarted nodes after the change in elasticsearch.yml? I find it more useful to use [templates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-templates.html) for your case, it's easier to change settings and you don't have to mess with elasticsearch.yml

Comment: yes i did, i restarted the service on each node in the cluster.
I think I found the issue, I found a template "default" with the following:

GET /_templates/default

{
"default" : {
"order" : 0,
"template" : "*",
"settings" : {
"index.number_of_replicas" : "0",
"index.number_of_shards" : "5"
},
"mappings" : {
},
"aliases" : {
}
}
}

When I try to PUT same json with different number of shards I get:

PUT /_templates/default

{
"error" : "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: template is missing;]",
"status" : 400
}

Comment: nvm, I was able to make the change! Thanks very much!

Comment: @user3352229 template was the problem?

Comment: Yes -- looks like template settings override global settings in elasticsearch.yml

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add primary shards without creating a new index and re-indexing all your data.

You can add replicas, but not primaries without reindexing. For a zero-downtime re-indexing scenario, check [this link](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index-aliases.html).